# SQL - group in one table for a max in another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do a (Microsoft) sql query to get the most recent order from one table for each product in another.  That is to say - the `group by` is in table B, while the `max` is in table A.  I tried a number of things, but this is the final.

```
WITH max_date(maxid, maxdate) as (
    SELECT inmost.PROD_ID as maxid
        ,MAX(inmost.ORDER_DATE) as maxdate
    FROM(SELECT od2.PROD_ID
            ,o2.ORDER_DATE
        FROM ORDERS o2 
            INNER JOIN ORDPRODS od2 ON o2.ORDER_ID = od2.ORDER_ID
        ) as inmost
    GROUP BY inmost.PROD_ID
)
SELECT o.ORDER_DATE
    ,od.ORDER_QUANT
FROM ORDERS o 
INNER JOIN ORDPRODS od ON o.ORDER_ID = od.ORDER_ID 
LEFT JOIN max_date mxord ON od.PROD_ID = mxord.maxid
    AND o.ORDER_DATE = mxord.maxdate
WHERE o.ORDERS_Canceled = '0'
```

At the end of things, it's still pulling multiple version of the each product and lots and lots of date for those products.  For instance:

```
PROD_ID    ORDER_DATE
111        1/1/2015
111        1/2/2015
112        1/2/2015
112        1/3/2015
112        1/4/2015
112        1/5/2015
```

What I WANT is:

```
PROD_ID    ORDER_DATE
111        1/2/2015
112        1/5/2015
```

Comment: Oops.  Changed mysql to sql.  Thank you.

Comment: @ConradFrix Conrad, if you put an answer I can accept that, because that's exactly what the problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join clause here means find matching Max_Date_mxord record on the ID and the date. Return all records found in od

`LEFT JOIN max_date mxord ON od.PROD_ID = mxord.maxid
    AND o.ORDER_DATE = mxord.maxdate`

To visualize this you can add `mxord.maxdate` to your SELECT clause and you'd likely see many nulls

However you want to exclude records in OD that don't match maxdate. To do that you want an INNER join.

Answer (score 0):

This is labeled as #mysql, but to my knowledge, MYSQL doesn't support the WITH clause, so I'm assuming this is SQL Server.

If that's the case, you could use the CROSS APPLY function, which would look something like this.

```
SELECT prd.PRODID, apl.ORDER_DATE
  FROM ORDPRODS prd
 CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 ORDER_DATE 
          FROM ORDERS ord
         WHERE ord.ORDER_ID = prd.ORDER_ID
           AND ord.ORDERS_Canceled = '0' 
         ORDER BY ORDER_DATE DESC
       ) apl
```